# Storing DaysOfWeek as single integer in sqlite database using enum/bitwise - Java

Tags: java, sqlite, casting, enums, bit-manipulation

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have a field that encompasses multiple days per week. (E.g. it can store MONDAY or MONDAY | TUESDAY, or WEDNESDAY | FRIDAY) - basically any combination.

To do this I used an enum with powers of 2, like this:

```
public enum DayOfWeek {
    Monday(1),
    Tuesday(2),
    Wednesday(4),
    Thursday(8),
    Friday(16),
    Saturday(32),
    Sunday(64);

    private final int index;

    DayOfWeek(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public int value() {
        return index;
    }
}
```

Then I store an integer in the database like this:

```
DayOfWeek days = DayOfWeek.Monday | DayOfWeek.Thursday; // Monday and Thursday
int daysAsInt = (DayOfWeek)days; // Value to save
```

I can test the days as such

```
if ((days & DayOfWeek.Monday) == DayOfWeek.Monday) /* If days contains Monday */
```

My problem is I'm not sure how to get that integer value converted back to the DayOfWeek. I thought I could cast it `(DayOfWeek)daysAsInt`. But it doesn't work.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: `DaysOfWeek.valueOf(<index>)` should give you the correct Enum element back. You would need to validate the range of `index` though.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your code won't compile even for the first part ("Then I store an integer...")

Comment: Unless the value is not one of the enumerated days of week.

Comment: why not reuse static field from Calendar, for example Calendar.MONDAY

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your enum is of *individual* days of the week - a variable of type `DayOfWeek` should only be expected to refer to a single day. If you're trying to store multiple values, you should look at an `EnumSet`:

```
EnumSet<DayOfWeek> days = EnumSet.of(DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Wednesday);
int valueToStore = setToValue(days);
```

Later:

```
int valueRetrieved = ...;
EnumSet<DayOfWeek> days = valueToSet(days);
```

where those methods are declared as:

```
static int setToValue(EnumSet<DayOfWeek> days) {
    int value = 0;
    for (DayOfWeek day : days) {
        value |= day.value();
    }
    return value;
}

static EnumSet<DayOfWeek> valueToSet(int value) {
    EnumSet<DayOfWeek> days = EnumSet.noneOf(DayOfWeek.class);
    for (DayOfWeek day : EnumSet.allOf(DayOfWeek.class)) {
        if ((value & day.value()) != 0) {
            days.add(day);
        }
    }
    return days;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that's what I needed to do. Was looking at some old code trying to figure out what was going on. Had some documentation about using the field as I described in the question - which was wrong.

Comment: `static int valueToSet(int value)` method declaration in this example is wrong, the example method returns an EnumSet so the declaration should be `static EnumSet<DayOfWeek> valueToSet(int value)`

Comment: @Andrew: Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Since the integer could contain multiple days you can't just simply convert the integer back to a single `DayOfWeek` instance but you'd have to return an array/set/list of `DayOfWeek` elements.

To do this, you could provide a static method in `DayOfWeek` and check the int for each "index" (which isn't really an index but rather a flag/id).