# Best practice to store days in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Hello I'm creating an android app.

I would like to know what would be the best practise to save and request a event on a special day.

I have a list of events that should repeat at different days.
For example I would like to have an event on Monday and Friday.
This event should only be shown on this days.

I found some solutions to store the data but I dont really know how to build the query for sqlite to request just selected day.
To store data I found this [Storing DaysOfWeek as single integer in sqlite database using enum/bitwise - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22204778/storing-daysofweek-as-single-integer-in-sqlite-database-using-enum-bitwise-jav)

But I dont know how to build the query for example just for monday in sqlite.

Or is there a better workaround?

Best regards

Comment: keep a timestamp,  see for example CalendarContract.EventsColumns

Comment: is this event calender Event in android ? Or it's a table in your sqlite db ?

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea And I even don't know it will work or not. I am Supposing Your Event is not calender event in android.

You can have one table with days and respective int values for it [same as java anum in the reference question link].

```
Day |  Value

Monday | 1

Tuesday| 2
.
.
.
.
```

**And while storing event , store day integer values with event**. (As you know days of each event)

And while querying , equate value in `event` table with the table above.

### OR

You can store directly string values like "Monday","Tuesday",... in event table directly.